Delphi 11 Form Caption change not working in run time
I use Embarcadero® Delphi 11 Version 28.0.48361.3236
I have some buttons on the form and the first I added is working, but later the new buttons I add is not visible on the form in runtime. They are visible in design....
When I change the caption text for the main form in designer, the text does not change when I run the program. It shows the previous title text, but not the new one???
I have never seen this before...
Hope to get some info on this.
Regards
Geir
I built the app and run it.
The form caption did not change.

Delphi version? Code? VCL or FMX? Screenshots? Also, your title says it does not work runtime, your text says design time.  Please [edit] your question.
